# Modfiying inflated inflated view in a dialogfragment after calling show()

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Let's say you have a `dialogfragment` with a `listView`. The title of the dialog is a custom view which is inflated in `onCreateDialog()`. Is it possible to toggle visibility of the inflated view when the list item is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onCreateDialog() function, you can hold the dialog view which referencing to title view which you want to toggle on. 
On click event of listview.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
//Toggle your title here
    }
});
```